# Tracking changes between master and project branches

Tags: java, git

Our QA team wants to know what areas we have changed between revisions and the possible UI locations these changes can affect.

Right now each developer is in charge of writing this out on their own tickets.   Then at the end of that project we use git to generate a diff of this branch vs master and manually trace each class to all possible UI locations.

This is eating up a lot of developer time and if UAT pushes a project back we have to do the whole process again.

We have thought about writing a program that looks at the source code finds all the files that contain the name of the class that changes.

We end up getting a lot of red herrings when we do this and runs over several hours.

Is there a better way to handle this preferably something we can put into our release management tools?

We are using Struts 2 and Spring to pull our application together.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: We are hoping that there are some ideas out there that are better then just looking at each file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> We have thought about writing a program that looks at the source code finds all the files that contain the name of the class that changes

You can use the `log` command

***`git log -- path_to_file`***

This command will print out all the commits which modified the given file name.

```
git log --stat -- <file to search>
```

---

#### Search for a string in all the commits:

```
# search for the given string in all the commits
git log -S"string to search"
```